# Nested For Each in PowerShell to pull out AD Group Membership for AD Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to pull out the members of a list of AD Groups, Get-ADGroupMember runs into an issue with the maximum number of members so I have tried to Get-ADGroup then expand the members but I don't get the output in the output file.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$LogDate = get-date -f "dd-MM-yy"

$groups = "Group1", "Group2", "Group3"


foreach ($group in $groups) {
   $results = Get-ADGroup $group -properties member | select-object -expandproperty member | ForEach {
   Get-ADUser "$_" -properties displayname,mail | Select GivenName,Surname,DisplayName,SamAccountName,Mail,enabled  
}

$results |
Select-Object @{Label = "First Name";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
@{Label = "Last Name";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
@{Label = "Display Name";Expression = {$_.DisplayName}},
@{Label = "Logon Name";Expression = {$_.sAMAccountName}},
@{Label = "Email";Expression = {$_.Mail}},
@{Label = "Account Status";Expression = {if (($_.Enabled -eq 'TRUE')  ) {'Enabled'} Else {'Disabled'}}},
@{Label = "Group";Expression = {$group}} | 

Export-csv F:\GroupMemberShip_$LogDate.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Sorry @RahulKumarShaw-MT but your answer is not very helpful.
   `Get-ADGroupMember` cannot specify the attributes requested, like `Mail`. He doesn't want mail of the group but mail of the user behind the member DN.
2. You cannot really guess what class the member's DN may be. So using `Get-ADUser` on a DN that point to a group would at best return $null. Using `Get-ADObject` is better when working on a link attribute like `member`.
3. This kind of script is generally incredibly slow for medium/large groups. Avoid unless you know your groups are really small.

### Better approach's but a bit more difficult

1. [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

I would personally use an [`Attribute Scope Query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.attributescopequery?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) which is a very fast and powerful LDAP Query.

- return the link to the DN member. (or object behind the DN)
- works for any link attribute, `member` being the most used.
- you can filter the members you want to return (i.e. only members with a mail by example by specifying a LDAP filter).
- you load only the attributes you're interested in.

The only issue with this request concerns multi-domain Active Directory environnements where a group contains a member from another domain than the group's domain. I don't know exactly what a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` would return, but generally it would normally return an error like `Partial Results` and allow access to a list of references that you can follow.
This may be combined with [`ReferralChasingOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.referralchasingoption?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) to check if references are automatically followed. But I don't think in an [`Attribute Scope Query`] request.

2. Range Request

Another option is to use Range Request to retrieve the member's DN really fast.
Then iterate over each DN (can even be done in parallel) to retrieve the desired attributes and filter if necessary. Generally this does involve using [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols] but some PowerShell modules exist on top of it like [S.DS.P](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/S.DS.P/2.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with below PowerShell Script and able to get the list of members of a list of AD Groups.

```
$groups = "Group1", "Group2", "Group3"
$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | select samaccountname, name, @{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}}
}
$results
$results | Export-csv C:\GroupMemberShip.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]
[image]

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c2e6bc41-30f8-444e-aa63-4cbedc79238f/get-members-list-from-multiple-ad-groups?forum=winserverpowershell